# Access phonegap API after redirect to external Website

Tags: api, cordova, external

I want to build an phonegap app an window.open call and API access. I find many threads about that, but nothing helps me.

Thats the way i call the external website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('https://www.domain.com','_self');
</script>
```

I think the solution with the iframe is very slow, the a like the window.open way, but it doesnt work with the API. The API calls are ok and works great, but only before the redirect starts.

UPDATE: I just try many solutions and read a lot of posts around that topic, but i wont work. I also added the cordova_plugins.js, but that throws errors. Hope anyone can help me, it makes me crazy.

Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

if you navigate away from the page, you unload cordova and all plugins (the javascript isn't there anymore on the new page)

embedding the external page looks to be the best choice.. or look how you can live without the api OR rewrite the external page to also load the same runtime :)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. How can i load the same runtime on the external site? Just include the cordova.js File?

Comment: are you able to edit the html on that site? if so .. load the js files (see your html's files <head> OR (and IMO likely) if you aren't able to edit it, write native plugins to insert the correct JS and when loading the other html --> quite some effort I daresay

Comment: Ok, i just put the JS File on the external website. Must i change the calls or something?

Comment: I just try to include the js file, but it doesnt work. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Sorry no. Never Tried it myself